# How to configure ElasticSearch to increase fuzziness between one-word strings

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm making a professional social app with a chat. I want to suggest users to add as a friend. The suggestions are based only on the title: developer, architect, singer ...

The current elastic query is too selective, hence I lack suggestions:

```
query: {
    bool: {
        must_not: {
            ids: {
                values: _usersToIgnore
            }
        },
        should: [
            {
                match: {
                    titlePhrase: {
                        query: title,
                        minimum_should_match: '90%',
                        boost: 2
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        minimum_should_match: 1
    }
}
```

I tried to lower **minimum_should_match** but it doesn't change nothing, I suppose that elastic matches words rather than letters.

The elastic mapping is:

```
titlePhrase: {
    type: 'text',
    analyzer: 'phrase_analyzer',
    search_analyzer: 'phrase_analyzer'
}
```

(I don't know anything about analyzers and it's not me who made this mapping)

In most of my cases, the titles are just one word. So Elastic finds:

- other users than share exactly the same title (ie: developer)
- users than share one word (ie: web developer, ios developer)

but it doesn't find any correspondance between:

- developer and dev
- bartender and barber (elastic doesn't care if a lot of letters are shared)

Do you know how can I increase the tolerance of elastic please ?
I can play with the fuzzy queries, But it seems hacky.

Comment: could you show mappings on titlePhrase?

Comment: Ok I edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to find correspondence between `dev` and `developer`, `bartender` and `barber` one could try to run [prefix queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html).

```
{ 
  "query": {
    "prefix" : { "titlePhrase" : "dev" }
  }
}
```

This would allow matches between same prefixes.